# Webpack outputs a minified but oversized JS file

Tags: javascript, webpack

I'm working with Webpack for JS minification. I'm importing 3 modules in one single minified bundle, but the final result is a huge file size for what is being imported (over 90kb) - they each look like this:

## 1:

```
var $ = require('jquery');

$(function() {
  // main expansion element
  $(".expander").click(function() {
    var subShown = $(this).children(".indented").css("display");

    if (subShown != "block") {
      $(this).children(".indented").css("display", "block");
      $(this).children(".caret").addClass("reversedCaret");
    } else {
      $(this).children(".indented").css("display", "none");
      $(this).children(".caret").removeClass("reversedCaret");
    }
  });
  // sub expansion element - .caret class is targeted as well due to issue with clicking on it not registering as a .sub-expander click
  $(".sub-expander, .caret").click(function() {
    var subSelectText = $(".sub-expander").text();
    if (subSelectText != "More") {
      $(".sub-expander").text("More");
    } else {
      $(".sub-expander").text("Show Less");
    }
  });
  // stop propagation on the link element within .expander class
  $(".indented").click(function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
  });
});
```

## 2:

```
console.log("a test message");

var clickButton = document.getElementById("clicker");

clickButton.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  e.target.classList.toggle("modified");
});
```

## 3:

```
class ColorPick extends React.Component {

constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    color: "Let's pick a color"
  };
}

changeColor(event) {
  var colorInput = document.getElementById('colorInput').value;
  this.setState({
    color: event.target.value,
    backgroundColor: event.target.value
  });

  if (colorInput === '') {
    this.setState({
      color: "Let's pick a color",
      backgroundColor: "#fff",
  });
}
}

render () {
  var styleObj = {
    backgroundColor: this.state.backgroundColor,
  };

  return (
    <section style={styleObj} id="Profile" >
      <h2 className="colorHeader">{this.state.color}</h2>
      <input id="colorInput" placeholder="Enter Hex Code Here" onChange={this.changeColor.bind(this)}/>
      <div id="slider"></div>
    </section>
  );
}
}

ReactDOM.render(<ColorPick name="connorcolorpicker" />, document.getElementById('color-picker'));
```

These three files by themselves clock in at 12kb total. However in the webpack minified bundle it clocks out at 90kb. That doesn't make sense to me. My webpack config looks like this:

**webpack.config.js:**

```
var debug = false;
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  context: __dirname,
  // entry is already defined in gulpfile.js - leave this line commented out.
  // entry: "/app/js/script.js",
  devtool: debug ? "inline-sourcemap" : null,
  module: {
    rules: [{
      test: /\.js$/,
      use: 'babel-loader'
    }],
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        query  :{
          presets:['react','es2015']
        },
        exclude: /node_modules/
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    root: [path.resolve(__dirname, 'app'), path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules')],
    extensions: ['', '.js']
  },
  output: {
    path: __dirname + "public/javascripts",
    filename: "scripts.min.js"
  },
  plugins: debug ? [] : [
    // new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin(),
    // new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({ minimize: true, mangle: true })
  ],
};
```

> [15:20:33] Version: webpack 1.15.0
>            Asset     Size  Chunks             Chunk Names scripts.min.js  90.1 kB       0  [emitted]  main

I was having issues with this in the past and the answers suggested to set debug to false. I did that but it isn't behaving as expected.

Why is 12kb worth of JS/imports totaling out to 90kb in Webpack?

Comment: react + jquery + your code?

Comment: Yeah they're different components

Comment: no I mean, react + reactDOM is 34.8 kb gzipped + jquery will make up 80+ kb

Comment: You can use the [webpack-bundle-analyzer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-bundle-analyzer) to try to find your culprit. It shows all the individual modules and their respective sizes.